# Name for spaces, such that each closed, pseudocompact subset is countably compact?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, compactness

Call a topological space "(* )", if each of its closed, pseudo-compact subsets is countably compact.

Does anyone know of a name for (* ), which appeared in the literature?

Since I'm just looking for any reference, I omit to give precise definitions.
Whether this name has been used in the T2 / Tychonoff context only or not, also doesn't matter.

Of course, normal, T2 spaces are (* ).
Moreover, a space is countably compact, iff it is pseudocompact and (* ).
This gives a lot of examples, which are not (* ).

A related, widely used notation is *isocompactness* (= closed, countably compact subsets are compact).
Obviosuly, a space is isocompact and (* ), iff each of its closed, pseudocompact subsets is compact.
Hence, a name for this property might also be helpful.

**Update** 
Just after posting this question, I noticed that "strong isocompactness" in this [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82675844.pdf) is similar to the second property, see Prop. 3.0. However, they are not identical, since "relatively pseudocompact" in this paper differs from "pseudocompact".